# Hide c# object in design mode (Expression Blend)

Tags: c#, wpf, object, hide, expression-blend

I have a DLL that contains all my object I need to build my application.

I want to hide some of them when I'm in Blend. For example, I don't want the graphic designer to use my base classes, so I need to hide them in design mode (Blend).

I tried to add [Browsable(false)] but it works only for a property or event.
I tried DesignTimeVisible(false)] but doesn't work either...

Is there a way to hide an object and not just a property? 
And I need it for Blend, because sometimes you can do something in VS but not in Blend.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you mean a *type* (probably class) rather than *object*. If you don't want the base class to be usable on its own, can you just make it abstract?

Comment: yes sometimes, but I also want to hide deprecated classes, that I cannot remove because they are used in some project, but I don't want to use them anymore

Comment: If you mark those as Obsolete, they should generate warnings anyway...

Comment: What I understand is there's no way that I can just hide a class? But yes you are right

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. I would try to remove the obsolete classes as quickly as possible, make the rest abstract, and the problem goes away in a *clean* manner. EDIT: Actually, BrowsableAttribute *can* be applied to all targets, not just properties and events...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this inside your XAML code-behind (or similar)

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
    // Do non-design mode stuff here}
}
```